# Разделение модели между модулями

Tags: архитектура

Имеем модель:

[image: Модель предметной области]

Она используется двумя (тремя, четырьмя) модулями для различных целей. Так, модуль Admin служит для модерации сущностей модели, а модуль Site для отображения модели клиентам. Каждый модуль накладывает собственные ограничения на сущности модели, так модуль Admin должен предоставлять пользователю все сущности модели, а модуль Site только соответствующие спецификации:

`Organizator.hideExcursions = false && City.isHide = false && Excursion.isHide = false`

Аналогичных критерий выборки, а так же механизмов взаимодействия с моделью в конкретном модуле может быть множество.

Вопрос: правильным ли решением будет реализация для каждого модуля собственной модели, использующей присущие именно этому модулю критерии и логику?

К примеру для модуля Site метод `getExcursions` класса `City` модели будет дополнен спецификацией:

`Organizator.hideExcursions = false && City.isHide = false && Excursion.isHide = false`

а для модуля Admin будет реализован отдельный класс `City` с методом `getExcursions` без использования этой спецификации.

Comment: под моделью вы имеет ввиду что?  какую архитектуру вы хотите использовать?

Comment: Под моделью я подразумеваю предметную область, спроецированную в приложении. Другими словами приложение в моем примере работает с Городами, Экскурсиями и Организаторами этих экскурсий, но оно реализовано в виде модулей. Модуль Admin используется для управления моделью, а модуль Site для демонстрации сущностей модели клиентам.

В данный момент используется парадигма DDD.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понимаю, тут речь идёт о банальном разделении прав доступа к объектам, а не о различных требованиях к сходным сущностям предметной области в различных ограниченных контекстах, когда действительно по фен-шую следовало бы для каждого контекста сделать свою реализацию.

В вашем случае, предполагая, что `City` - это все-таки агрегат, а не какой-то аналог репозитория, `getExcursions` должен обращаться к некой абстракции, которая и должна уже а) проверять права на доступ для текущего пользователя (security layer), б) получать нужные сущности с учётом ограничений, наложенных слоем безопасности (persistence layer). Вариантов реализации слоя безопасности в DDD огромное множество, прекрасный документ на эту тему [по ссылке](https://www.utwente.nl/ewi/trese/graduation_projects/2008/Uithol.pdf).

Comment: Речь в первую очередь о разделении ответственности. Модули Admin и Site это два разных приложения, разделенных физически. Мне интересна архитектура, позволяющая модулю Site всегда видеть только ограниченные некоторых критерием Экскурсии. Здесь не имеют значения права доступа, так как к модулю Site могут обращаться только клиенты, организаторы же работают с помощью модуля Admin.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, >к модулю Site могут обращаться только клиенты, организаторы же работают с помощью модуля Admin - да, но объекты-то одни и те же. и к определённым из них получить доступ может только определённое лицо. на мой взгляд это как раз права доступа к объектам.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, а архитектуру я описал примерную. некая асбстракция выдаёт нужный список в зависимости от того, какой запрос получает (от админа/пользователя, из одного или другого модуля, называйте, как хотите).

Comment: > и к определённым из них получить доступ может только определённое лицо
Дело в том, что на уровне модуля эти лица не идентифицируются. То есть модуль Admin всех принимает за админов, а модуль Site всех за клиентов.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, в выше сказанном это ничего не меняет. Идентифицируйте не пользователя, а модуль. Можно, конечно, сделать разные реализации сущностей модели, но это против DRY и очевидные сложности в поддержке. Если не хочется ничего идентифицировать вообще, то сделайте просто разные реализации той абстракции, о которой я говорю выше, для разных модулей. В итоге City и его внутренняя логика будут одними и теми же в разных модулях, но будут обращаться к разным сущностям для получения экскурсий.

Comment: То есть запрос экскурсий города будет выглядеть как то так:
`$city->getExcursions($excursionsRepository);`
?

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, ну, логика примерно такая, да. По хорошему это надо делать через паттерн стратегия, то есть City в конструктор получает зависимость на репозиторий, что-то типа IRepository, в методе getExcursions от него вызывается метод Get. В разных модулях в конструктор передаются разные реализации IRepository. Это решит проблему, но, честно говоря, всё это далеко от хардкорного DDD, потому что сущность предметной области ничего не должна знать о persistence layer.

Comment: > честно говоря, всё это далеко от хардкорного DDD
В том то и дело, что я ищу кошерную реализацию этого. Я понимаю, что можно просто использовать везде репозитории, но не считаю это правильным решением. Возможно вам будет проще понять задачу, если скажу что в контексте конкретного модуля любые запросы Экскурсий должны удовлетворять условию `excursion.isHide = false && excursion.organizator.isHide = false`, то есть и на уровне репозитория, и на уровне множественной ассоциаций любой сущности с Экскурсиями.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, как вариант опять же здесь можно инъецировать не репозиторий, а сервис какой-то доменный. или вообще пользоваться ambient context или всем сразу.

Comment: Проблема в том, что City создается на уровне ORM, а она не умеет инъектировать зависимости в конструктор сущности.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov в конечном счёте всё это упирается в использование какого-то слоя, который будет выдавать нужный набор сущностей в зависимости от запроса. Вариантов, куда это разместить - тонна. Начиная от запросов различных хранимых процедур БД в различных модулях заканчивая слоем безопасности с идентификацией пользователя. Может действительно сделать разные интерфейсы получения данных со стороны базы/веб-сервисов?

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov, с ORM всё прикольнее, конечно, становится.

Comment: Да, в ORM то основная загвоздка и зарыта ) Хочется, чтобы запрос $city->getExcursions() учитывал те же базовые спецификации, ограничивающие выборку экскурсий, что и запрос $excrusionsRepository->findAll(), а именно в выборку не должны входить скрытые экскурсии. Простейшим решением является реализация выборки на стороне репозитория экскурсий и передача его в метод getExcursions города, но меня смущает это решение добавлением явной зависимости методу. Хотелось бы реализовать это как то более прозрачно, чтоб City не знал о наличии каких либо доп. спецификаций.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov Может быть все-таки ambient context? С доступом к репозиториям от статического класса по типу Application.Current? Тогда инъекций ни в метод, ни в конструктор не будет, а инициализация контекста проходит где-то в точке входа в модуль.

Comment: Сущности ведь в любом случае нужно получить доступ к контексту, будь то через Service Locator или другую явную зависимость? Я плохо знаком с этим паттерном, чтобы судить.

Comment: @Artur-Mamedbekov  По факту это просто обращение к статическому классу. Это зависимость, да, но она не влияет на интерфейс класса.

Comment: Как вариант, буду рассматривать. Спасибо.